# discord.py: How to get age of user's account?

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

I want to check if the a user's account is more than 30 days old when he joins (`on_member_join`). If not, the bot should send a message to a channel. I have problems how to get the account's "age".

##### Example

```py
bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # this obviously doesn't work
    if not member.age.days > 30:
        channel = bot.get_channel(ID)
        await channel.send("Your account age is too young to join this server!")
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `discord.py` documentation, you can use the `created_at` attribute of a `discord.User` or `discord.Member` class. It will return a `datetime.datetime` object.

```py
>>> myaccount = client.get_user(my_id)
>>> myaccount.created_at
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 6, 14, 22, 14)
>>> myaccount.timestamp()
1375813334.0
>>> time.time() - myaccount.timestamp() > 2592000 # 2592000 seconds is 30 days
True
```

You can incorporate this into an `on_member_join` client event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if time.time() - member.created_at.timestamp() < 2592000:
        # do stuff if the account is young #
    else:
        # do stuff if the account is not young #
```

Comment: Do I have to import time? Like this:
`import time`

Comment: Yeah, like you said with `import time`. You can also change the number 2592000 to whatever you want (that is just 30 days in seconds)

Comment: I tested it. But the bot still sends a message even though the account is over a year old.

Comment: Sorry, I got the operands in the wrong direction. It should be `time.time() - member.created_at.timestamp() < 2492000`