# Discordpy - Autoban fresh accounts

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Is there a way to ban fresh accounts like accounts that are 20days old? I couldnt find any thing on the documentation of the discord.py site.

For example:
Member joins, bot checks the age of the accounts. if below <20 days, ban

Comment: Does that maybe help you? [Check when user was created and joined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980266/how-to-check-the-creation-date-of-an-user-in-discord-py#:~:text=From%20the%20discord.py%20documentation,It%20will%20return%20a%20datetime.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `user.created_at` within `on_member_join` to find out the account age when the person joins.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.created_at